# Remove rich text format while keeping line breaks in MVC View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, formatting

I have a field containing rich text formatting where the data is most likely to be a paragraph set out as multiple lines in a list.

I want to show that in a view and remove the formatting but keep the linebreaks so that the list items are still separated.

What I have below (C# within the cshtml) removes the formatting but displays the items on the same line, how can I change this to get what I need, or is there a better way?

```
 MyModel.Synopsis =   Regex.Replace(rtfField.ToString(), "<.*?>", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for an answer to this, I just added the following style to the label displaying the data:   white-space: pre-wrap;